# PHP persistant connections to MySql trouble

Tags: php, mysql

Our servers are in some situation that I need some direction on how to debug. I have reviewed other questions here and on stackoverflow. I have not found any posts within the last few years that would direct me with my situation.

How can I debug PHP to MySql persistent connections?

How can I make sure that the persistent connections are reused?

On heavy load days we notice that the number of database connections climb. After some time we see that most of the connections will go idle. When there are new requests more connections are created.

$conn = new mysqli('p:host:port', 'database_user', 'secrets_are_kept', 'database_name');

From what I have read on php.net all that is needed to be done to setup persistent connections is to change 'host' to 'p:host' when creating the connection.

Comment: This belongs on StackOverFlow.  However, the fact you have a bunch of idle connections means they are persistent.  When the script using the connection is done you need to close the connection at least then you won't have any dormant connection laying around.

Comment: I started out on stack overflow and was redirected to here. Secondly I would call close() on the db variable and set it to null. It seems to have no effect.

Comment: There are many different types of mistakes that could cause this, without some better idea what the code is like I can only guess.  If you had you mysqli statement inside a for loop then each time the for loop was executed a new connection would be established and the old ignored, but that is only one of dozens of possibilities.

Comment: These systems are funny. When I started this question I was asked what type of question do you have? I selected it is troubleshooting. I was then redirected to superuser. Then my question has now been sent back to stackoverflow. Interesting. How do I ask troubleshooting questions in stackoverflow without having to route through superusers?